# Get last record making multiple searches in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one table called `Products`.

**Fields**

- product_id
- Type (IN or OUT)
- Date (date of registration)

I have several entries in the table, with entries and product outputs with their respective dates.

How do I find products that do not have `OUTPUT` movement after the `LAST ENTRY`?

I already tried:

```
SELECT Products.product_id, Products.Type, MAX(Products.Date) 
FROM Products PRODUCTS_1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Products PRODUCTS 
  ON PRODUCTS_1.Product_Id = PRODUCTS.Product_Id 
  AND PRODUCTS_1.Type='O'} 
WHERE (PRODUCTS.Type='I') 
  AND (PRODUCTS_1.Date>PRODUCTS.Date) 
GROUP BY Products.product_id, Products.Type;
```

Comment: Please include what you have already tried.

Comment: Marcelo, welcome to SO! :) Please, take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to earn your first shiny badge ;) Also, as Brody wrote, you should edit your question and write what you already tried + some code etc... It will help other to answer.

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle or something else? There is a `}` in `AND PRODUCTS_1.Type='O'}` that probably is not correct. I'd recommend you use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to show us your table structure of PRODUCTS with dummy data and expected reuslts

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. ignore "}" please.
SELECT Products.product_id, Products.Type, MAX(Products.Date) 
FROM Products PRODUCTS_1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Products PRODUCTS 
  ON PRODUCTS_1.Product_Id = PRODUCTS.Product_Id 
  AND PRODUCTS_1.Type='O' 
WHERE PRODUCTS.Type='I' 
  AND PRODUCTS_1.Date>PRODUCTS.Date 
GROUP BY Products.product_id, Products.Type

Comment: What is `LAST ENTRY`? Please [edit] again, add some sample data, and show the results you'd like to obtain from that data. It's difficult to understand what you're asking without it. Also, what data type is the `Products.Date` column? (Is it actually DATETIME, or is it something else? It's relevant, and many questions here asking about how to do something with dates are not using actual DATETIME columns.)

Answer (score 1):

This query will list all products for which the latest entry is `I`. I think that's what you are asking for.

```
SELECT p.product_id
  FROM products p
 GROUP BY p.product_id
HAVING MAX(Date) = MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'I' THEN Date END)
```